# how to find and deploy the correct files with Bazel's pkg_tar() in Windows?

Tags: bazel

please take a look at the bin-win target in my repository here:
https://github.com/thinlizzy/bazelexample/blob/master/demo/BUILD#L28

it seems to be properly packing the executable inside a file named bin-win.tar.gz, but I still have some questions:

1- in my machine, the file is being generated at this directory:

> C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp_bazel_John\aS4O8v3V\execroot__main__\bazel-out\x64_windows-fastbuild\bin\demo

which makes finding the tar.gz file a cumbersome task. 
The question is how can I make my bin-win target to move the file from there to a "better location"? (perhaps defined by an environment variable or a cmd line parameter/flag)

2- how can I include more files with my executable? My actual use case is I want to supply data files and some DLLs together with the executable. Should I use a filegroup() rule and refer its name in the "srcs" attribute as well?

2a- for the DLLs, is there a way to make a filegroup() rule to interpret environment variables? (e.g: the directories of the DLLs)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look for the `bazel-bin` and `bazel-genfiles` directories in your workspace. These are actually junctions (directory symlinks) that Bazel updates after every build. If you `bazel build //:demo`, you can access its output as `bazel-bin\demo`.

   (a) You can also set `TMP` and `TEMP` in your environment to point to e.g. `c:\tmp`. Bazel will pick those up instead of `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp`, so the full path for the output directory (that `bazel-bin` points to) will be `c:\tmp\aS4O8v3V\execroot\__main__\bazel-out\x64_windows-fastbuild\bin`.

   (b) Or you can pass the [`--output_user_root`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--output_user_root) startup flag, e.g. `bazel--output_user_root=c:\tmp build //:demo`. That will have the same effect as (a).

   There's currently no way to get rid of the `_bazel_John\aS4O8v3V\execroot` part of the path.
2. Yes, I think you need to put those files in `pkg_tar.srcs`. Whether you use a `filegroup()` rule is irrelevant; filegroup just lets you group files together, so you can refer to the group by name, which is useful when you need to refer to the same files in multiple rules.

   2.a. I don't think so.

Comment: I am not sure whether the bazel-bin and bazel-genfiles symlinks will also work on Windows.

Comment: (a) and (b) seem to be good options to define an output dir, but I still have the problem of discovering the "aS4O8v3V" hashed directory (or I can just set the output_user_root to some unique dir and then just "jump" six levels there)

Comment: [@thinlizzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918643/thinlizzy): The bazel-{bin,genfiles} symlinks do work on Windows. Bazel can create directory symlinks ("junctions" in Windows' lingo) on all Windows versions it supports, starting from Win7. Bazel-on-Windows currently cannot create file symlinks though.

Comment: [@thinlizzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918643/thinlizzy): You can ask Bazel about the output directory: `bazel info output_root`. Run `bazel info` to see the list of all values `info` can retrieve.

Comment: is this file symlink issue the reason that I can't normally open files in my data dependencies when I do a bazel run in *Windows* ? (the same files open fine when I do bazel run in Linux)